Getting over the roblox leaderstats intvalue limit
I am making a game that requires a large amount of values, I have it so there are two values: StringValue and IntValue. The intvalue holds the number of the clicks that the player has and then the main script takes the value from the intvalue shortens it and make it look like "100k" but when I go over 9.2Qi or something like that it will be 0 or it won't go up anymore please help me out here.

well if you look at the documentation of the IntValue you can see its stored as a 64bit value. this means the maximum value is 9.2 quintillion and you cant go higher than that using a IntValue.

An IntValue can only store values up to 263-1 or around 9.2 quintillion which is the limit you are reaching. Since you are going over that limit, you are causing an integer overflow which restarts your value at zero.

An IntValue stores a single signed 64-bit integer. The highest allowed value is 2^63-1 or around 9.2 quintillion (9.2^18); attempting to store larger numbers will cause integer overflow. The lowest allowed value is -2^63 or about -9.2 quintillion. Practically, however, working with integers larger than 2^53 (9.0^15) will cause loss of precision since Luau uses double-precision floating-point to store numbers.
— https://create.roblox.com/docs/reference/engine/classes/IntValue

They are two ways around this, one is to use a library like BigInteger or BigNum or to store values as a string  if you are willing to lose precision.
Storing Numbers as a String
If you are willing to sacrifice precision can store numbers as a string to bypass the 9.2 quintillion limit and then use tonumber to convert that string into an number whenever we want to use an arithmetic operation.
In the below example, have Money and ExpensiveItemCost. The Money we have is above the IntValue maximum so we use a StringValue. When we are subtracting ExpensiveItemCost from Money we make sure to use tonumber to convert the Money which is a string into a number we can use
local ExpensiveItemCost = 1e+105

-- Use StringValue instead of IntValue
local Money = Instance.new(“StringValue”, workspace)

Money.Value = '9e+105' -- Above that maximum IntValue can handle

-- Use tonumber because Money.Value is a string
Money.Value = tonumber(Money.Value) - ExpensiveItemCost

print(Money.Value) -- 8e+105

From https://devforum.roblox.com/t/1344993
Using a Library for Large Numbers
There are many libraries you can use to handle large number, because it's best to refer to the library's documentation on how to properly use them.
For this example, I will be using BigInteger but you can choose any library you like or that fits you for your Roblox experience.
This example does the exact same the above does but uses a math library for handling large numbers so we don't lose any precision.
-- Require the BigInteger module
local ReplicatedStorage = game:GetService("ReplicatedStorage")
local BigInteger = require(ReplicatedStorage.BigInteger) -- Set this to where BigInteger is located

-- Use BigInteger when we're dealing with large numbers
local ExpensiveItemCost = BigInteger.new('1^105')

-- Use StringValue instead of IntValue
local Money = Instance.new(“StringValue”, workspace)

Money.Value = tostring(BigInteger.new('9^105'))

-- Convert Money.Value string back to BigInteger
Money.Value = tostring(BigInteger.new(Money.Value) - ExpensiveItemCost)

print(Money.Value) -- 8e+105


While both ways work they are cons and pros to each. Using the first option is more easy and simple but costs precision. The second method is more precise but is more complex and requires using a third-party library.
